# How to get the text in a backBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

does anyone knows how to get the text content of a backBarButtonItem when using a UINavigationController ? It's the name of the previous view but I'd like to get it in the next view.

[image: backBarButtonItem]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to get the title of the previous viewController in the navigation controller viewController stack:

```
((UIViewController*)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.viewControllers.count-2]).title
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a UIBarButtonItem using:

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title style:(UIBarButtonItemStyle)style target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
```

Then you attach the target to your method and you can pop the controller in your method.

Answer (score 0):

It's property of `UIBarItem`: `backBarButtonItem.title`

Comment: Check self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIViewController* backController = (UIViewController*)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:[self.navigationController.viewControllers count] - 2];
NSString* backTitle = backController.navigationItem.title;
```