# Get title of backBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, backbarbuttonitem

I'm currently writing an app with multiple users.
I would like to use the same "Profile" view in storyboard to display info for all the users.

The plan was to set the title of the "Profile" view and then push it.

```
 - (void) pushGeneralProfileViewFrom:(UIViewController *)target usernameAsTitleOfView:(NSString *)title {

    UIViewController *myView = [target.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GeneralProfileView"]; // created in storyboard, Feed View
    myView.title = title;
    [target.navigationController pushViewController:myView animated:YES];
}
```

This worked great. However, the "profile" view also has buttons that lead it to other views in the storyboard. Those views also display specific info for the relevant user.

I was planning to use the name of the backBarButtonItem to know the user I need to display the info for. While I can see the back button with the username in the simulator, I'm unable to get it's `self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title` or `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title`. Both return `null`.

What am I doing wrong?
Also, I have a feeling this is not the best practice to handle those kind of things. I've searched the web and so far haven't seen a better way to pass values to a view I'm pushing. Suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the text in a backBarButtonItem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018129/how-to-get-the-text-in-a-backbarbuttonitem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `backBarButtonItem` that you see when your view controller is visible in the navigation controller interface is not the `backBarButtonItem` of *this* view controller. It is the `backBarButtonItem` of the *second* view controller, the one behind this one in the stack.

So what you want is this:

```
UIInteger c = [self.navigationController.viewControllers count];
UIViewController* vc2 = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:c-2];
```

Now get the `backBarButtonItem` of the `navigationItem` of *that* view controller. Or just get its `title` if they are the same.

Comment: Worked like a charm :)
Thank you.